# how to install slider in magento 2 on Ubuntu?

Tags: magento, installation, slider, magento2

I am trying to install the slider extension in Magento 2 on ubuntu manually. I am new to Magento, if anyone has a solution please let me know.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy the extension code to app/code/[EXTENSION_PROVIDER]/[EXTENSION_NAME] (create the 
   directories). You can find exactly the extension provider and name inside the 
   module/registration.php.
   Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::register(
   \Magento\Framework\Component\ComponentRegistrar::MODULE,
   '**PROVIDER_NAME**',

   2. From command line run php bin/magento module:enable Provider_Name
   3. php bin/magento setup:upgrade
   4. Take a look at your magento admin, probably you should see some section to
      add and customize your slide.

That's it

Answer (score 0):

1. Copy contents of the extension to your Magento app/code folder. Once completed, the folder
   structure should be “*app/code/[vendor_name]/[module_name]*” (*without quotes and square brackets*).

   **VENDOR_NAME** and **MODULE_NAME**, you can find from module/**registration.php**

   Example :-

   ```
   ComponentRegistrar::register(ComponentRegistrar::MODULE, 'Invigorate_Imageslider', __DIR__);
   ```

   **VENDOR_NAME** :- Invigorate

   **MODULE_NAME** :- Imageslider
2. In the command line console (in the magento root directory), run ***bin/magento setup:upgrade*** to
   enable and install the module.
3. Flush your Magento caches, e.g. **bin/magento cache:flush**
4. The module is now installed. Please login to the admin to verify.
5. you can check if module is installed and enabled by **bin/magento module:status Invigorate_Imageslider**